# JSON format in Arduino

Tags: c++, json, post, nodemcu, arduino-c++

I have a code that works fine if I input the values directly, but my current system is such that the values would have to change. see the code below.

```
char http_cmd[] =  "POST /tracker/ HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 38\r\nHost: haul1.herokuapp.com\r\n\r\n{ \"trackerId\": \"2222\",\"height\": \"42\" }";

// this works fine
```

but I want to input the values as variables, so I did something like this

```
String tracker = "2222";
String height = "42";
char http_cmd[] =  "POST /tracker/ HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 38\r\nHost: haul1.herokuapp.com\r\n\r\n{ \"trackerId\": \""+tracker+"\",\"height\": \""+height+"\" }";
```

this is the Error message I get

```
exit status 1
initializer fails to determine size of 'http_cmd'
```

**Thank you** as you attempt it. **what I really need is an acceptable syntax of Json content type, I also need to know how to get the exact size of the "http_cmd"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two errors in your code. The error you see is because you create an `char` array without specify the length. There is another error that String concatenation with `+` is part of the Arduino String library, it is not part of c++ and therefore is not a valid operator for data type `char`.

There are two ways to do it, 1) using String concatenation operator `+` from String library (all you need is to change your code from `char http_cmd[]` to `String http_cmd`); 2) using char array. But it is generally consider safer to use char array than String library. You can use `sprintf()` to create a string array, this works for all data type except for floating point in Arduino.

For easy to calculate the length of the json payload and for readability, it is better to break the command into several strings. BTW, I assumed that the `tracker` and `height` are really `int` which can be encoded in JSON directly.

```
int tracker = 2222;
int height = 42;

// create json payload
char json[30];
sprintf(json, "{\"trackerId\":%d,\"height\":%d}", tracker, height);

char http_post_request[] = "POST /tracker/ HTTP/1.1\r\n";
char http_content_type[] = "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";

// calculate payload length
char http_content_length[20];
sprintf(http_content_length, "Content-Length:%lu\r\n", strlen(json));
char http_host[] = "Host: haul1.herokuapp.com\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: I think I understand your approach but after using this I get a new error `expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token `. I would appreciate if you can help me with this.

Comment: The error does not come from the part of my code. But I think that I know why you get the error, the code that I show need to be in a function where you send your request, such as in the `setup()` or the `loop()` or any function you created, since you never post your complete sketch, I just show you want need to be done but I have no idea where the code should be in your sketch.

Comment: Basically the function like `sprintf()` can't be put as a global level on top of your `setup()` and `loop()`, it need to be within a function. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573190/4902099) for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out. Solved

Comment: Glad I can help. please consider [accepting it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This would be considered String concatenation at this point. The + operator will return type `String` not `char[]`. Have you tried creating the string first in a separate variable and calling `.c_str()` on it?

from what i can see the json syntax itself looks fine if you skip past all the http stuff appended before it.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I learnt something tangible from your answer.